# How to track celery and rabbitmq in production server

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery, celery-task, rabbitmqctl

I have installed both celery and rabbitmq. Now i would like to track how many messages are there in the queue and how it is distributed, want to see the list of celery consumers and tasks they are executing etc. this is bcoz i had issues with celery getting stuck when there is a memory pressure. I tried installing rabbitmq management for a start and when i tried to login at myservr.com:15672 it said can only be used through localhost, is there any workaround? Also is it a good idea to run such monitoring on production servers? Will there be any chance for memory leaks?

Comment: Yes, the Rabbit Management plugin is what you want - installation [instructions here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html). The plugin also provides a [JSON Api](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.5/priv/www/api/index.html) which you can use to programmatically monitor your queue depths and exchange throughputs. AFAIK the plugin has minimal performance impact, and most would regard it essential to monitor your production cluster in real time.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helpful